# How to delete row number using C programing?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a `Structure`, in the `Structure`I have an `Array`,

I read a text file and then open it in `Array Into Structure ',

What I have is a list of names, Last, results.

so what is the best way to find a row number and select which row to delete and delete it? I said, `Array` into a `Structure`.?

I know I can use `memmove` and `realloc` but how do I use these?

Comment: Is this really C, or are you mistaking C for C++?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far?

Comment: ok can update my questions....

Comment: So essentially you want to delete a row from an array? You can't do that in C. Arrays are just a sequence of bytes -- deleting a row would be the equivalent of destroying a few bytes on your RAM. You can, however, move the rest of the elements behind so it looks like you deleted an element.

Comment: Yes actually I can do that, by using memmove and realloc, somthing like this .... :)

Comment: That is overwriting the array with further rows, really -- it's a shift and resize. But if you know the answer, what's the question then?

Comment: the question is how I use these functions `memmove`and `realloc`? :)

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 check this out >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156468/how-to-delete-a-row-from-an-array-in-structure

Answer (score 1):

Well, all you can do is move the following elements towards the start, and decrease the "logical" length. The logical length is different from the physical length, which is the maximum number of elements the array can hold, based on how much memory has been allocated.

So, assuming an array starting at `array` and with `count` elements, code to delete the `n`:th element would be:

```
if( n < count - 1)
  memmove(array + n, array + n + 1, ((count - n) - 1) * sizeof *array);
--count;
```

This copies the following elements (unless you're deleting the very last one, in which case there's nothing to copy) and then decreases the logical length.

Comment: ok, i'll uppdate my code and you will se what I exactly mean .;)

Comment: @unwid check this out >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156468/how-to-delete-a-row-from-an-array-in-structure